# Put VM on WD MyBook

Tags: vmware-workstation, mybook

I put a few  guest OSes on [mybook](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Digital_My_Book). So, when I need to do my work, I would power on the mybook and use the VMware workstation to start the visualization.

Since I would have to access mybook for a long period of time, and since working inside the virtual OS would cause constant read/write to the harddisk itself. I afraid that what I do would degrade the performance of mybook, significantly shorten the lifespan of it or worse, increase the risk of bad sectors on the mybook hard disk.

Is my fear warranted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been running various linux distributions from Western Digital Passport drives for the last few years. I have not lost any files or suffered any corrupted data that could not be fixed.

It's designed to be used heavily, so I say use it.

Here's an interesting comment [I found here](http://ask-leo.com/should_i_turn_off_my_external_hard_drive_when_not_in_use.html) -

> A study by Google a while back concluded, among other things, that if the drive doesn't fail within the first year (so called "infant mortality") it's actually likely to have a relatively long and healthy life.

Answer (score 0):

Since your Mybook contains a standard hard disk, there should be no difference to other hard disks built into your computer.